# Necessary to close a returned refcursor from a stored plpgsql function or not?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, database-cursor

Using PostgreSQL I store a function using the following structure:

```
create or replace function myfunc() returns refcursor as $$
declare rc refcursor := 'mycursor';
-- ...
begin;
    -- ...
    open rc for select ...;
    return rc;
end; $$ language plpgsql;
```

This returns a cursor which I'm using in a mandatory transaction. Which I'm using like this:

```
begin;
select myfunc();
fetch all in mycursor;
close mycursor;
commit;
```

But in most examples and tutorials, the statement `close mycursor;` is simply omitted.
I know you need to close it when using it internally in the function, but when it's returned, maybe the `commit;` automatically closes any open cursors?
So, is closing the cursor really necessary?

Not sure how to check if it's still open after the `commit;` since the cursor is not in scope anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [mention in the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/plpgsql-cursors.html)

> CLOSE closes the portal underlying an open cursor. This can be used to release resources earlier than end of transaction, or to free up the cursor variable to be opened again.

You can use `close cursor_name` for `releasing resources earlier than end of transaction`, so if you don't close the cursor and `end` or `commit` your transaction then it shouldn't matter at all.